Pods having different Cached Values
I have implemented a C# .NET InMemoryCacherService with reference to another cacherService that was previously implemented.
Problem: The cache, for testing, now reloads every 15 minutes. It is deployed. I am expected response - "disabled" from the application for the next 15 minutes. What I see though, is "disabled", "200 OK" alternatively or in some pattern.
When I checked the logs of the pods, it looks like one pod has all the 400 (disabled) responses, and one had the 200 responses.
I'm not sure why this is happening? Previously the same type code was deployed in AKS and it was working fine. Why is this not working the same way? Am I missing some configuration/ docker / deployment setting?
I was under the impression that if there's two pods, they are replicas and will have same cachedMemory, am I wrong?
My cacher Service just has some tables from DB - converted to lists, and a reloading function that reloads cache after specified interval of time. The interval is specified in configuration settings.
